# Radius of convergence of the series $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n!\,z^{2n}}{(1+n^2)^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, power-series

I am doing the following problem and would like to know whether my answer is correct or not:

Find the Radius of convergence for the complex series $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^n \frac{z^{2n}n!}{(1+n^2)^n}$. I found it to be $R<1$. I used the relation $n!=cn^ne^{-n}$ and eventually got $|\frac{z^2}{e(1+n^2)}|$<1 and eventually $|z|<1$. Thus, is my work correct? Any inputs are well appreciated!

Comment: @Peter: The above is formula is Stirling's approximation. I left out the term $\sqrt(
2\pi n)$ because it will essentially be some constant

Comment: Did you use the theorem of hamadard ?

Comment: @Peter: No, I made a regular substitution and with some arithmetic I got the relation for radius of convergence. We haven't learn any major theorem in complex analysis yet

Comment: The radius of convergence is not $1$.

Comment: @Peter: Use the ratio test and work the problem step by step and things will be clear.

Answer (score 4):

First we should notice that: The radius of convergence of
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^{2n}
$$
is $r$ if and only if the radius of convergence of
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^{n}
$$
is equal to $r^2$.

In our powerseries, with $z^2$ replace by $z$, using the ratio test we have
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\frac{(n+1)!}{(1+(n+1)^2)^{n+1}}}{\frac{n!}{(1+n^2)^{n}}}=
\frac{\frac{n+1}{1+(n+1)^2}}{\left(\frac{1+(n+1)^2}{1+n^2}\right)^n}=\frac{\frac{n+1}{1+(n+1)^2}}{\left(1+\frac{2n+1}{1+n^2}\right)^n}\longrightarrow \frac{0}{\mathrm{e}^2}=0.
$$
Therefore, the radius of convergence of $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^n \frac{z^{n}n!}{(1+n^2)^n}$ is $r=\infty$ and so in the radius of convergence of $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^n \frac{z^{2n}n!}{(1+n^2)^n}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** 
Use the *[root test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test)* and note that $n!<n^n$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** It is easier to use the ratio test.

Comment: I have tried that strategy but I was stuck because I couldnt figure out how to handle $\displaystyle\frac{(1+n^2)^n}{(1+(n+1)^2)^{n+1}}$